# I can't push my commits to my Github repository in Choreo

Tags: github, repository, git-push, wso2-choreo

Created an API by giving a Github repository in Choreo, and edited the code. After that, committed the code. When executing `git push`, it asks for the username and password. After pressing enter, an error was coming as `Authentication failed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with your GitHub credentials. As the error message states, GitHub does not allow to use the password to authenticate in CLIs. You have to use a PAT (Personal Access Token) for this. If you use a PAT for as a password, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

if it is saying
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed

try this

you can check your credentials using

git config --global --edit

once you are inside the config edit, follow this steps

1, Edit your Git configuration file (.gitconfig) and remove the lines containing your PAT and the extraheader configuration.
2, Ensure that the GitHub CLI is installed and properly set up on your system.
If you are using GitHub CLI's credential helper (gh auth git-credential), it should handle the authentication process for you.
3, You might need to reauthenticate with GitHub CLI. You can do this by running gh auth login and following the prompts.

then git pull.